# Trouble with returning a correct element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got three links which serve as sorting headings for a table, each is a member of the "sort" class. I wrote a simple jquery function that gets triggered when any "sort" class link is clicked. There's a switch case that assigns a certain column number (columnNum) to be used with the tablesorter plugin. However, right now I'm getting some weird values returned for the id of the sort classes.

```
$(".sort").toggle(function() { 
    // the column id's are datecaption, hourscaption, taskcaption
    var column = $(this).attr('id');
    var columnNum;

    switch(column){
        case 'datecaption':
            columnNum = 1;
            break;
        case 'hourscaption':
            columnNum = 2;
            break;
        case 'taskcaption':
            columnNum = 3;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    var sorting = [[columnNum,1]]; 
    $("#task_table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
    return false; 
}, function(){
    var sorting = [[columnNum,0]]; 
    $("#task_table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
    return false;               
});
```

If I alert the column variable, I get "aeaoofnhgocdbnbeljkmbjdmhbcokfdb-mousedown"--which doesn't serve the rest of the function well.

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more code or the HTML it's hard to say.  My guess is `$(this)` isn't what you think it is.  Try adding `console.log($(this));` (preferably in Firebug) click the result and you will see what `$(this)` is actually referring to.

Additionally, you could query the DOM for `$('#aeaoofnhgocdbnbeljkmbjdmhbcokfdb-mousedown')` and see and you should get the element `$(this)` is referring to.

For more information on what "this" will refer to in different situations, check out the Mozilla Developer Network:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Yes, it turns out I was looking for the encasing span's ID, not the link's. I didn't know about logging to the console before so that's an invaluable tool for the future. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Just an FYI since console.log is new to you.  Make sure you take it out of 'production' code.  Some browsers such as IE don't have a console defined, unless developer tools are open.  So you'll get nasty undefined errors!

Comment: you can also use something like  if(!console || !console.log){ console = {}; console.log = function(msg){}; } to prevent errors.  There are a lot of other really useful console functions as well, http://getfirebug.com/logging